# php write file issue

Tags: php, xml

I am currently working on a PHP script that creates an xml file. When I run the script in a browser it does not get written out. When I use the shell command "php /filelocation" it works just fine. Why is this?

```
<?php
include('parse.php');

$test;

$test[0] = "Name:Actinium";
$test[1] = "Symbol:Ac";
$test[2] = "Atomic number:89";
$test[3] = "Atomic weight:[227]";

xml_write($test);
?>

<?php
function xml_write($s)
{
  $temp = explode(":",$s[0]);
  $data;
  $count = 0;

  for($i = 0;$i< sizeof($s);$i++)
    {
      $temp = explode(":",$s[$i]);
      $data[$count] = $temp[1];
      $count++; 

    }
  //creates the root element
  $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
  $root = $xml->createElement("table");
  $xml->appendChild($root);

  //creates name element
  $name = $xml->createElement("name");
  $nameText = $xml->createTextNode($data[0]);
  $name->appendChild($nameText);

  //creates symbol element
  $symbol = $xml->createElement("symbol");
  $symbolText= $xml->createTextNode($data[1]);
  $symbol->appendChild($symbolText);

  //creates atomic number element
  $number = $xml->createElement("number");
  $numberText = $xml->createTextNode($data[2]);
  $number->appendChild($numberText);

  //creates atomic mass element
  $mass = $xml->createElement("mass");
  $massText = $xml->createTextNode($data[3]);
  $mass->appendChild($massText);

  //creates "element" element and binds the properties to it
  $ele = $xml->createElement("element");
  $ele->appendChild($name);
  $ele->appendChild($symbol);
  $ele->appendChild($number);
  $ele->appendChild($mass);

  //attaches ele to root
  $root->appendChild($ele);

  $xml->formatOutput = true;
  echo "<xmp>".$xml->saveXML()."</xmp>";

  $xml->save("/home/anthony/database/table.xml") or die("Error");
}
```

Comment: There are a few possible reasons. File permission errors; trying to write to the wrong place. Maybe you could edit your question to include your code?

Comment: what are the permissions like on the directory you are writing to? are you writing to an actual location or a relative path?

Comment: Please post some of your code for us.

Comment: going off of the permissions. Is the script being run by apache when called from the browser (no suexec)? This would prove why it works from the shell as the user

Comment: The script is being run by apache. I am writing it to an actual location and the file has both read and write permissions

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't setting a content-type of 'application/xml' or similar via `header()`, then the browser is trying to render xml as html... it will appear as a blank page. You should be able to see some output if you "view-source" from the browser.

Or you can set a content-type header, and the browser will display it as XML.

**Edit**

After re-reading I may have mis-interpreted. I thought you were simply `echo`ing the data out. I would have to concur with the above commenters that whomever the apache process is running as does not have permission to the file.

To rule out permissions you could possibly (depending on host) set the path to `/tmp/table.xml` and see if it works. Assuming a permissions issue, then the apache user (www-data maybe?) will need rw permissions on the file. If apache is to create a new file, it'll need rw permissions on the parent directory as well.

Comment: The script is being run by apache. I am writing it to an actual location and the file has both read and write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem before. My best guess is that the r/w permissions are only given to the owner and not _www, which causes the shell command to work and browser access to fail. If you can, try `chmod 666` and see if that works.

Alternatively, you can go to your Apache's httpd.conf file and change the User from _www to your username. But I would not recommend this as a permanent solution because it opens up a lot of potential security issues.